# livelink integration with asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, repository, integration, document

I am building a standard asp.net LOB application. i am planning to have some livelink urls showing up in some parts of the application, where the user clicks a download link and the document needs to be downloaded from the corresponding livelink URL and a save-as dialog needs to come up.

for any direct http document URL, it is possible to use httpwebrequest and fetch the contents and stream it back to the browser. but with livelink URLs, there is a some page redirect where the current request acquires some cookie state and then the resulting URL is allowed to access the document content.

i was wondering if there are any standard APIs/webservices that allow integration with livelink, such that a handshake can be done and a given document can be retrieved.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have at least 2 options:

1. Construct the LiveLink URL correctly - this can be done by specifying the "func" to "doc.fetch", the "nodeid" and the "vernum" to the relevant document
2. Another option is to use the LiveLink API (LAPI). It's a good-enough API, that is quite easy to pick up.

Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, Livelink provides .NET/Java Web services for certain functionality.

However, if all you require is to display the save/open/cancel dialog then you can just use the following url from an anchor tag:

```
http://<server>/livelink/llisapi.dll?func=ll&objId=<nodeid>&objAction=download
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been using a webservice for downloading Livelink documents in an application I have created for migrating a livelink application to Sharepoint.

Comment: A bit of self-promotion here, but if you're doing LiveLink to SharePoint migration, check out this: http://www.tzunami.com/products/Pages/TDLiveLinkMigration.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Livelink 9.7.1 and higher has a complete .net webservices API.  You can download the SDK from the OpenText KnowledgeCenter.